# Error after updating Angular 4.0.1 to 4.3.1

Tags: angular

I am getting this error

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

as I am navigating to pages in my application.This error started coming when I have upgraded angular 4.0.1 to 4.3.1 Please tell me the fix. I seen on many post there is patch for this error using `ChangeDetectorRef` but it seems to be not working in my scenario.

Comment: this is a code error @Priyanka . where while navigating the ui component value changes from what it was earlier , you can make use of `change detectionref` or `setTimeout` in order for the work around or make sure the varaible value dosent change while routing. this [link](https://medium.com/@golbie/angular-2-change-detection-what-the-hell-is-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-82007cdfa38a) may help

Comment: As Rahul wrote, it's a problem in your code. To fix it, it's necessary to learn why it happens. Check some [articles](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) about it and try to find the problematic code.

Comment: It's a known issue, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18970

Comment: Actually thatis workaround & our application is very huge.So we cant make changes to many places.Just wanted to know why is that issue coming( root cause) after upgrading.